# Windows Authentication WCF and ASP.Net MVC2: getting users AD info to a wcf webservice

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-2, windows-authentication

Hello there fellow StackOverflow and programming enthusiasts.  I have a question, I am trying to move an MVC website that I created over to a test server so that users can start testing... I have run into a little issue that I overlooked when I developed the site.  My website calls a service that I wrote that takes takes the service callers AD user name and uses it to do some back end work...

```
    private string CallerNameOnly = string.Empty;
    private string CallerFullDomain = string.Empty;

    public ACOService()
    {
        this.CallerFullDomain = OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Name.ToString();
        this.CallerNameOnly = this.CallerFullDomain.Substring(this.CallerFullDomain.IndexOf('\\') + 1);
    }
```

This worked just perfectly when I was developing on my local machine and my username was passed into the service just fine...  However, I am having a hard time replicating the same functionality when I deploy to a server that I am using...  For some reason, the current user ends up being my machine name...
Now, I seemed to have isolated the issue to a setting in IIS 7 that when changed, changes the behavior of my website somewhat...  If I go to the app pools advanced settings and I change the Process Model/Identity field, from LocalSystem, to any of the other Identity's It changes who the user is... My remote debugger kept bugging out on me so I couldn't figure out what the user name was, but you get the idea?
My question is, how do I get the username of the person using my website (which uses windows authentication) to call my web service with the username he used to access my site?  I thought about getting the username and passing it directly into a constructor ie...

```
    public ACOService(string userID)
    {
        this.CallerNameOnly = userID;       
    }
```

but that presents problems, because I already have a constructor with a string in it.  And I think I would have to place the constructor into my contract wouldn't I?  How would that work in WCF anyway?
Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you disable anonymous access in the IIS settings? What happens when you do not allow anonymous access and only use windows authentication for the website in IIS?

Comment: Ok, and what kind of binding do you use for the WCF service? Did you set up any authentication for them?

Comment: NetTCPBinding.  I really didn't set up any authentication settings for that binding.

Comment: Impersonation perhaps may be my ticket?

Comment: Ok, NetTcpBinding has Windows Authentication (transport security) by default. Under which identity does the WCF server run? You can try setting `<identity><dns /></identity>` on your endpoint. I don't think you need impersonation though, the authentication should pass through. I've set it up successfully before, but I don't have access to that config anymore, sorry.

Comment: Is there another way I could reference the caller in my service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to impersonate the client on the service.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731090.aspx

Comment: I have impersonated the client on the service, And I am still getting an error indicating that my user isn't being used by my webservice.  By Impersonate, I mean, I call the impersonation code when I setup my client, and I have that attribute that set's impersonation up on my service contract's implementation.  
[OperationBehavior(Impersonation=ImpersonationOption.Required)]
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel =
    System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
Still nothing is working... :-(  Help!!!!

Comment: Do you need to call the System.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principle.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation everytime you call the client, or just the first time?